# simple condition not using isNan?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, alert

I am adding input a and input b, and if there is no selected input in the html, this alert returns 'nan', and I am trying to use an if statement to catch the 'nan' and under that condition, print a different message if they did not enter a number, but called the function (clicked the button)

```
function add(a, b) {
    var sum = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
    if(isNan(sum) === false){
        alert('please enter an integer');
    }
    alert(sum);
}
```

Comment: Look in the browser's developer console. If the code in your question is the actual code you're running, you will see an error there.

Comment: If you use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number you shouldn't need this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put wrong function format

Convert this

```
if(isNan(sum) === false)
```

to this

```
if(isNaN(sum) === false)
```

and also update your condition, just check for `true` value

```
if(isNaN(sum))
```

Comment: thanks, this was the simple answer I was looking for, I appreciate Your quick response.   also, Your demo link did not load ?

Comment: @DennisWPaulsenJR Please ignore the demo link. I have removed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `===false` from condition. Something like

```
if (isNaN(sum)) {
 alert('please enter an integer')
}
```

Comment: You might want to note the other change you made to the code as well as the "Just remove..." part. (No need to reply to this comment, I'll remove it after you edit the answer.)